# How to change the default value of check_box ? in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

How to change the default value of check_box ?

views/doctors/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@doctor) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :pass %><br>
  <%= f.check_box :pass, {checked: true, checked_value: "yes", unchecked_value: "No"}  %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The data type of :pass attribute was `string`, But still it was not created any value for `:pass` attribute in DB. So, I changed the data type of :pass attribute into boolean.

Now it is working with `True and False`

But, I Just want to change the `True and False` into `Yes and No`

Please someone help me.

Comment: whats not working. Post your error

Comment: Now the value of attribute ":pass" is saved as True if check_box is checked and false if not checked. But, I want to change the value "True" into "Yes" and "false" into "No".

Comment: checked_value: "yes", unchecked_value: "No" is not working

Answer (score 8):

According to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box), the correct syntax is:

```
check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

So, you should change your code to this:

```
 <%= f.check_box :pass, { checked: true }, 'yes', 'no'  %>
```