# Default the checkbox to unchecked in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am updating a Rails 2.3.18 legacy application. For some reason, the following code is giving me a checkbox that is checked instead of unchecked. This happens even when I turn off javascript, so I think I've ruled that out:

```
f.check_box("college", {}, "y", "n")
```

The output in HTML is

```
<label id="college" for="user_college" style="display:block;">
    <input name="user[college]" type="hidden" value="n"><input checked="checked" id="user_college" name="user[college]" type="checkbox" value="y"> <span>Some copy here.</span></label>
```

I reviewed https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/check_box and do not see an option to default to unchecked. Is there an option with f.check_box to default to unchecked?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484343/how-to-change-the-default-value-of-check-box-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @MoamenNaanou unfortunately, that post does not show how to make the input default to unchecked. From what I can tell, the code I've used should be unchecked because I haven't specifically included "checked" in the {} options. Any ideas?

Comment: My current solution is to use jQuery with something like the below, but while this works, I want to see if there is a way to get a similar result with the check_box: $('#college :checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass `:checked => false` to second param of `f.check_box` method:

```
f.check_box("college", { :checked => false }, "y", "n")
```

or ruby new syntax:

```
f.check_box("college", { checked: false }, "y", "n")
```